How to set root bone's pivot?
Normally in pose mode if I try to rotate the root bone this happens - it rotates on it's pivot point: 
I want to permanently set it's pivot somewhere else so I can rotate the root bone without having to keep clicking on the spot and rotating by using 3D cursor like this: 
I tried setting origin point of the armature to that point but in pose mode it still rotates on it's default pivot.

Anything against "make the bone bigger" or "add a parent bone"? (Bones aren't supposed to "strictly" follow some good looking proportion, but to enable the kinds of movements you want, even though they might go outside the mesh for that purpose)

Actually adding an extra bone could be the easiest way, thank you!

So, my two suggestions are:

Make the bone bigger (so that it's pivot point is the point you want)
Add an extra parent bone

Bones are designed to enable the kinds of movements you want, even though they might go outside the mesh for that purpose. They don't necessarily need to be good looking or match the mesh perfectly.
